# Select max data with 3 tables

Tags: sql, date, select, max

I can't get the right results.
I have 3 tables:

```
table: Aluno
id_aluno    nome
1           Bruno
2           Carlos

table: Serie
id_serie    id_aluno    descricao
1           1           Tipo A
2           1           Tipo B
3           2           Tipo A

table: Treino
id_treino   id_serie    data
1           1           2015-12-10
2           2           2015-12-12
3           3           2015-12-10
```

I want the following results:

```
nome     descricao    data
Bruno    TIPO B       2015-12-12
Carlos   TIPO A       2015-12-10
```

The problem is that the GROUP BY clause should have column "id_aluno" but it's not foreign key of the table which has the date. There is a intermediate table between them. I don't know how to do.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Sorry, SELECT MAX DATE

Comment: It is a good idea to include SQL in the question, even if it doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables based on the existing keys, but you would then need to specify that you want the max date based only on the person, something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.nome,
    s.descricao,
    t.data
FROM Aluno a
    JOIN Serie s
        ON s.id_aluno = a.id_aluno
    JOIN Treino t
        ON t.id_serie = s.id_serie
WHERE t.data = ( --get max date by person, excluding serie
                SELECT MAX(t1.data)
                FROM Aluno a1
                JOIN Serie s1
                    ON s1.id_aluno = a1.id_aluno
                JOIN Treino t1
                    ON t1.id_serie = s1.id_serie
                WHERE s1.id_aluno = s.id_aluno 
               )
```

Comment: Using this query be sure to have unique `data` values in `Treino` otherwise there can be duplicates in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group By` on any column of the `From` tables including those linked through `Join`. You can use `Join` to link as many tables as you need.

```
Select Aluno.nome, Serie.descricao, Max(Treino.data) As data
From Aluno
Inner Join Serie On Serie.id_aluno = Aluno.id_aluno
Inner Join Treino On Treino.id_serie = Serie.id_serie
Group By Aluno.nome, Serie.descricao
```

OK, with the comment in mind for MS SQL it can be written like that:

```
Select nome, descricao, data
From (
    Select Aluno.nome, Serie.descricao, Treino.data,
        RANK() OVER (Partition By Aluno.nome Order By Treino.data Desc) AS Ordinal
    From Aluno
    Inner Join Serie On Serie.id_aluno = Aluno.id_aluno
    Inner Join Treino On Treino.id_serie = Serie.id_serie
) Ranked
Where Ordinal = 1
```

By the way, what should happen if you have another record in Treino:
`4, 1, 2015-12-12` or `5, 2, 2015-12-12` for that matter?
You need a way to prioritize Serie too. Say, like that:

```
Select nome, descricao, data
From (
    Select Aluno.nome, Serie.descricao, Treino.data,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Aluno.nome Order By Treino.data Desc, Serie.descricao) AS Ordinal
    From Aluno
    Inner Join Serie On Serie.id_aluno = Aluno.id_aluno
    Inner Join Treino On Treino.id_serie = Serie.id_serie
) Ranked
Where Ordinal = 1
```

Comment: I tried this already, but it's returning all max dates from each serie (because it's on group by clause), and I need all the max dates from each aluno.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```js
Select a.nome, s.descricao, t.data
FROM Aluno a
join Serie s on (s.id_aluno = a.id_aluno)
join Treino t on (t.id_serie = s.id_serie)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have did it using the multiple Common table expressions.

**Script**:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT TOP 2 id_Treino,id_serie,data
    FROM Treino
    ORDER BY DATA DESC
), 
cte2 
as
(
    SELECT a.nome,s.descricao,c.data
    FROM aluno AS a
    INNER JOIN Serie AS s
    ON a.id_aluno = s.id_aluno
    INNER JOIN cte AS c
    ON s.id_serie = c.id_serie
)
SELECT * FROM cte2;
```

**Output**:

```
nome        descricao       DATA
------------------------------
Bruno       Tipo B      2015-12-12
Carlos      Tipo A      2015-12-10
```